# New thread inside AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm just getting started with threading so I have a question. Why does a new thread (different from the background thread) gets created when I call the method initOctoshape() from doInBackground() in this case ? Thnx!

```
public class PlayerActivity extends CustomActivity implements 
                                          ProblemListener{

 public class PlayChannel extends AsyncTask<Channel, String, String> {
     Channel channel; 
     PlayerActivity thisActivity;

      @Override
      protected String doInBackground(Channel... params) {
             Thread.currentThread().getName();
             channel=params[0];  
             thisActivity=channel.thisActivity;
             initOctoshapeSystem(thisActivity);

      return url;
      } 
 }


 public void initOctoshapeSystem(Activity thisActivity) {
       os = OctoStatic.create(thisActivity, thisActivity, null);
       os.setOctoshapeSystemListener(new OctoshapeSystemListener() {
            @Override
            public void onConnect() {
                 Thread.currentThread().getName();
                 mStreamPlayer = setupStream(OCTOLINK);
                 mStreamPlayer.requestPlay();
            }
      });
 }

 public StreamPlayer setupStream(final String stream) {
    StreamPlayer sp = os.createStreamPlayer(stream);
    sp.setListener(new StreamPlayerListener() {
        @Override
        public void gotUrl(String url) {
        }
    });
 return sp;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `doInBackground(Params...)` method of `AsyncTask` always gets executed on a background thread, and since you call the `initOctoshapeSystem(thisActivity);` from this method, it will also execute on this background thread. That's the behavior of `AsyncTask`.

So,

> a new thread (different from the background thread) gets created when I call the method initOctoshape() from doInBackground()

is incorrect. Your call to `initOctoshape()` only follows the thread that drives `doInBackground()`.

Comment: Thnx for replying. But how come that if I put this line of code `Thread.currentThread().getName()` within the overridden onConnect() it provides a name different from the name of the background thread? I've edited my code.

Comment: The `onConnect()` is a different method than `initOctoshapeSystem()` and thus can be executed asynchronously - I'm not familiar with this 'octoshape' library, but it must be that the `OctoshapeSystem` fires `onConnect()` on another thread. The best course of action is to consult the documentation of the lib on that.